# What does ".....in the year to June 2023" mean? Is it starting from January of 2023 or is it starting from June of 2022?

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

**A record 510,000 people came to Australia in the year to June 2023.** [BBC-Australia to halve migration](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-67609963)

I know the difference between **fiscal year** and **calendar year**, but this one does not seem to be about financial issues. So, I think it must be referring to the calender year, which means it must be covering 6 months of 2023. Still, I can't be 100%.

So, is **"...in the year to June 2023"** referring to the 12 months starting from June of 2022 or is it starting from January of 2023 and covering only the 6 month of this year?

Comment: Spelling - calend**a**r. The 'year to' any month is the preceding 12 months. So from June 2022.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Thanks Michael for the answer.

Comment: _The year to 2023_ doesn't mean anything. If they had meant six months they would have said _the first half of 2023_ or _January to June 2023_.

Comment: @KateBunting - the title needed editing to match the question.

Comment: For American English, I don't find the expression clear or acceptable and would assume there was some editing mistake.  If forced to give it meaning, I would assume they meant "in this year up to June 2023," covering 5 months of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could mean either:

- The 12 months ending June 2023 (ie July 2022 - June 2023)
  **or**
- The year 2023 up to June (ie Jan 2023 - June 2023)

The context could be clearer, but I would assume it is the former, because for it to be a *record* it must be being compared against other years (or other 12-month periods). I would only expect the latter meaning to apply if data for an incomplete year was being presented alongside other years.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker, nor can I access the cited article due to my location, but you can take this into consideration:
[Year-to-date - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year-to-date)